# Using R to map seedling locations using set reference points

Tags: mapping, cluster-analysis, spatial, raster, nearest-neighbor

I'm looking for some guidance on the approach I should take to mapping some points with R.

Earlier this year I went off to a forest to map the spatial distribution of some seedlings. I created a grid—every two meters I set down a flag with a tagname, and what I did is I would measure the distance from a flag to a seedling, as well as the angle using a military compass. I chose this method in hopes of getting better accuracy (GPS Garmins prove useless for this sort of task under canopy cover).

I am really new to spatial distribution work altogether, so I was hoping someone could provide guidance on what R packages I should use.

First step is to create a grid with my reference points (the flags). Second step is to tell R to use a reference point and my directions to mark the location of a seedling. From there come other things, such as cluster analysis.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions asking for recommendations on how to find a tool or software library are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. A more effective question to help you get the help you want would be to show what you have understood to do so far and what you've tried. Any particular reason why `R`? Have you tried researching with Glorious Google for spatial distribution work? Do you have a specific example of perhaps the information you are trying to organize so that you can apply it through code?

Answer (score 0):

The largest R package for analysing point pattern data like yours is `spatstat` which has a very detailed documentation and an [accompanying book](http://book.spatstat.org/).

For more specific help you would need to upload (part of) your data so we can see how it is organised and how you should read it in and convert to standard x,y coordinates.

**Full disclosure: I'm a co-author of both the package and the book.**